# How to group the same values which is in sequence order

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I'm trying to group data in sequence order. I have the following table:

```
id  num
-------
1   1
2   1
3   1
4   2
5   1
6   2
7   2
8   4
9   4
10  4
```

I need the SQL query to output the following:

```
num       count(num)
-------------------    
1          3    
2          1    
1          1    
2          2    
4          3
```

Sample data:

```
select * into #temp 
from (
    select 1 as id, 1 as num union all
    select 2,  1  union all
    select 3,  1  union all
    select 4,  2  union all
    select 5,  1  union all
    select 6,  2  union all
    select 7,  2  union all
    select 8,  4  union all
    select 9,  4  union all
    select 10, 4 
) as abc
select * from #temp
```

select num, count(num) 
from #temp 
group by num

I need this :

```
num       count(num)    
-------------------    
1          3    
2          1    
1          1    
2          2    
4          3
```

The actual output :

```
num    count(num)    
---------------------    
1       4    
2       3    
4       3
```

Comment: You've told us what you "need", but you haven't told us your question. What are you asking here? (No, "Please write my SQL for me" isn't a question.) What have you tried so far, and why didn't it work?

Comment: I suggest search on gaps and islands questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a gaps and islands problem. Here is one way to solve it using `lag()` and a cumulative `sum()`:

```
select min(num) num, count(*) count_num
from (
    select t.*, sum(case when num = lag_num then 0 else 1 end) over(order by id) grp
    from (
        select t.*, lag(num) over(order by id) lag_num
        from #temp t
    ) t
) t
group by grp
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddlde](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=39dd7181031645f452c7bb6cbfee948e)**:

```
num | count_num
--: | --------:
  1 |         3
  2 |         1
  1 |         1
  2 |         2
  3 |         3
```

Answer (score 1):

Another Approach can be using `row_number`

```
select num, count(*) 
       from (select t.*,
             (row_number() over (order by id) -
              row_number() over (partition by num order by id)
             ) as grp
             from #temp t
            ) t
group by grp, num;
```

[**DBFIDDLE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e2374a623d1788f2ce30377126cd65bd)

Answer (score 1):

Gaps and islands problems are fun because there are so many different ways to address them.  Here is one approach that does not require aggregation -- although it does require more use of window functions.

This is possible because the only information you are requesting is the count.  If the `id` has no gaps and is sequential:

```
select num,
      lead(id, 1, max_id + 1) over (order by id) - id
from (select t.*,
             lag(num) over (order by id) as prev_num,
             max(id) over () as max_id
      from temp t
     ) t
where prev_num is null or prev_num <> num
order by id;
```

Otherwise, you can generate such a sequence easily:

```
select num,
      lead(seqnum, 1, cnt + 1) over (order by id) - seqnum
from (select t.*,
             lag(num) over (order by id) as prev_num,
             row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum,
             count(*) over () as cnt
      from temp t
     ) t
where prev_num is null or prev_num <> num
order by id;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=58ee9608b6ab15ce3f1a23a562789562) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: This is a nice solution too!